# Missing basis step while solving a recurrence inductively

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

While solving the recurrence
$$T(n) \leq (n-1) +\frac{2}{n} \sum_{i= n/2}^{n-1} T(i)$$
our professor directly went to the hypothesis step without showing the basis step. Here the hypothesis step is:

> Assume inductively that $T(i) \leq 4i$ for $i < n$.

Edit: Here is complete context:

> Let $T(n, k)$ denote the expected time to find the $k$-th smallest in an array of size $n$, and let $T(n) = \max_k T(n, k)$. We will show that $T(n) < 4n$.
>
> First of all, it takes $n-1$ comparisons to split into the array into two pieces in Step 2. These pieces are equally likely to have size $0$ and $n-1$, or $1$ and $n-2$, or $2$ and $n-3$, and so on up to $n-1$
> and $0$. The piece we recurse on will depend on $k$, but since we are only giving an upper bound, we can imagine that we always recurse on the larger piece.

What would be appropriate basis step for this recurrence ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is related to [tag:computational-complexity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-complexity). Can you explain with more detail? What you have wanted to do? Sorting an array?

Answer (score 0):

$$T(i)\le4i\text{ for }i<n,$$ for some $n$ which depends on the problem on hand (I cannot guess).

E.g. $$T(1)\le4,T(2)\le8.$$

Comment: Updated the Question. Thanks